# Get span Id's of selected text using getSelected()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird problem. I don’t quite know how to approach it. We have an application that spits out paragraphs of text with each and every word wrapped in a span with an ID. I am being asked to make a JavaScript to capture the ID's of all the words that a user highlights.

So a simple example of a paragraph is below.

```
<span id="p-58" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(-58);return false"> that </span>
<span id="p177" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(177);return false"> quake </span>
<span id="p857" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(857);return false"> briefly </span>
<span id="p1697" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(1697);return false"> triggering </span>
<span id="p2267" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(2267);return false"> another </span>
<span id="p2697" class="softWord" onClick="setTranscriptPosition(2697);return false"> tsunami </span>
```

I know there is a way to capture the selected text using something like this:(found this at site http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html)

```
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
        else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
                    else {
                            var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
                            if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

How would i get the id's of those spans though?

Comment: I dont know what is `setTranscriptPosition(-58)`. But i think with the combination of jquery `mouseup` and your javascript code you can do it, easily. Do something like On mouseup call `getSelected()`, if its just a click it will return false it other wise you can get the id of the span.

Comment: We did exactly this on a project.  Hang on, I'm filtering out the code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this will do exactly what you need.  It's thanks to my friend's work on a project we did together, so the credit belongs to him:

http://jsfiddle.net/KC48j/11/

Just select some text and hit the button.  *EDIT*: updated to work with IE as well.  You can mess around with the logic yourself (how it handles whitespace between words is up to you).

Comment: @Milimetric: A couple of points: In the `window.getSelection` branch, you should check that the selection has some ranges using its `rangeCount` property (which can be 0). Also, Firefox allows multiple ranges per selection (notably this happens when you select multiple cells in a table), so you should also allow for that. See my answer.

Comment: @Tim Down: cool.  I think in cases where you're doing things like this you have pretty tight control of the html and "duct tape and string" coding is sometimes better than robust solutions like Rangy.  Interesting though, thanks for providing the insight.

Comment: @Milimetric: Agreed, I wouldn't always use the weight of a library like Rangy for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a library, my [Rangy library](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) makes this pretty simple. The following will work in all major browsers (including IE 6):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VC3hk/24/

Code:

```
function getSelectedSpanIds() {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection(), ids = [];
    for (var r = 0, range, spans; r < sel.rangeCount; ++r) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(r);
        if (range.startContainer == range.endContainer && range.startContainer.nodeType == 3) {
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.selectNode(range.startContainer.parentNode);
        }
        spans = range.getNodes([1], function(node) {
              return node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span";
        });
        for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; ++i) {
            ids.push(spans[i].id);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}

document.onkeyup = document.onmouseup = function() {
    alert(getSelectedSpanIds());
};
```

Comment: This example capture ids only when more than a word is selected. Is it possible to select only one word and capture its id?

Comment: @Pankus: Updated.

Comment: many thanks for your help (I'm very impressed!). Just one question. Why `range = range.cloneRange();`; `range = sel.getRangeAt(r);` is not enough? Excuse me for this question, but this first time I face with this topic

Comment: @Pankus: Because `range.selectNode` changes the range and in some browsers (I forget the details), altering a range that came from the selection alters the selection as well. In other browsers `getRangeAt` returns a copy of the selected range so there would be no need to copy it. See [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#dom-selection-getrangeat).

Comment: but what happens with a more complex node hierarchy? For example, if one of the spans contained child nodes (e.g., `<span id="p2697" class="softWord"> text0 <span class="something">tsunami <u>text3</u> text2</span> </span>`), the script only works if one clicks on text0 (http://jsfiddle.net/pankus/xrL0fb9e/4/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your over complicating it, just use mouseup()

**jquery**

```
$('span').mouseup(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Check it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/Qdv4T/

Comment: unless of course you select multiple spans and want to return the id of all, this method wont work. Is that what you require?

Comment: This only seems to return the id of one word though.