# How to get all attributes or ids by selecting html text with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

let me first explain my issue.
I'm working on a webpage which prints a long text with data retrieved from a db. Each word of the text has is own id (which in turn is a primary key).
I'm wondering if it is possible to select portion of text with mouse and contextually collect all the ids of this selection.
At present, I tried with a very simple click function:

```
var idList = []
$('.tags').click(function() {
   var feature = [this.id, this.text];
   idList.push(feature);
   info.innerHTML = idList;
});
```

However, it is not very handy becouse of users must click on every word to collect data. At the same time I tried with`window.getSelection()` and the way it works is perfect for my needs, but as far I can understand it returns only a string with all selected words and does not their attributes.

**EDIT, Oct 10 2017**
This question may already have an answer here:
[Get span Id's of selected text using getSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637430/get-span-ids-of-selected-text-using-getselected)

Yes, this is true indeed, but the solution proposed are fairly different.
I find very interesting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5637790/5541592) solution because it is a true selection method and it seems to work pretty well on multi line texts. At the same time the solution proposed here by [Taurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575458/5541592) is very interesting: as far as I can understand it does not fit well for multline selelctions ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/pankus/bmm5sg6b/)),  but anyway it offers the opportunity of selecting non-contiguous portions of text, as well as to deselect a single selection, which are both very important for my small project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get span Id's of selected text using getSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637430/get-span-ids-of-selected-text-using-getselected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var word_list = [];
var add_mousemove_event = true;

$(document).on("mousedown", "p > span", function(){

if($(this).hasClass("word_selected")) {
$(this).removeClass("word_selected"); 
remove_word_from_array($(this).attr("id"));
} 
else {
event_callback.call($(this)); 
} 

}).on("mouseup", "p > span", function(){
$(document).off("mousemove", "p > span", event_callback); 
add_mousemove_event = true;
});

function remove_word_from_array(word_id) {
for(let i = 0; i < word_list.length; i++) {
if(word_list[i]["word_id"] === word_id) {
word_list.splice(i, 1);
break;
}
} 
show_selected_word_ids();
}


function event_callback() {
exec($(this)); 
}
 
 
function exec(elem) {
if(add_mousemove_event === true) {
$(document).on("mousemove", "p > span", event_callback); 
add_mousemove_event = false;
}

select_words.call(elem); 
} 
 
function select_words() {
if(!$(this).hasClass("word_selected")) { 
word_list.push({
"word_id": $(this).attr("id"),
"word_text": $(this).text() 
});

$(this).addClass("word_selected"); 
show_selected_word_ids();
}
}

function show_selected_word_ids() {
var word_list_container = $("#word_list_container");
word_list_container.html("");
for(let i = 0; i < word_list.length; i++) {
word_list_container.append(word_list[i]["word_id"] + (i !== word_list.length - 1 ? "," : ""));
} 
}
 
});
```

```css
.word_selected {
background-color: lightsteelblue;
border-bottom: 2px solid indigo;
}

p {
user-select: none;
cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<span id="1">My</span>
<span id="2">Name</span>
<span id="3">Is</span>
<span id="4">Jon</span>
<span id="5">Snow</span>
<span id="6">And</span>
<span id="7">I</span>
<span id="8">Know</span>
<span id="9">Nothing</span>
</p>

<p id="word_list_container">
</p>
```

Obviously, this won't work on mobile because the events are browser-based, but you get the idea, you just have to change the events to touch-based ones and everything should work just fine. Also, you can embellish this snippet as much as you want, I recommend adding a "clear all" button as well.

In the meantime, feel free to ask any questions you might have on the snippet I provided. I would have commented it but I am going to sleep right now, I will possibly comment the code tomorrow, it should be fairly easy to read though.

Comment: I edited my question with some information taken from another answer. For your experience, is it possible to modify your snippet in order to obtain a true selection behaviour (also for multi line texts)? At the end of the work I would like to obtain something similar to the [automator.js](http://annotatorjs.org/) plugin (the problem with that plugin is that apparently there is no method to get the ids)

Comment: @Pankus But my implementation does work on multi-line text.

Comment: @Pankus And what do you mean by "a true selection behavior" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach:

1) Create an array with all words and their IDs, as objects.

```
var arr = [{"id":1111, "text":"Hello"},
           {"id":2222, "text":"World"}]
```

2) With ***window.getSelection().toString()***  you should have exactly the string selected by the user. Adding ***.split(' ')*** you will have an array with the words. There could be a problem with other symbols (?!@ etc) but you could easily fix it (for example, you may want to use *regex* or *filtering*, in order to have a 'clean' array of words).

```
var words = window.getSelection().toString().split(' ')
```

3) Once you have the array of selected words, loop through each one and push each id to your *idList* array.

```
for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
        if words[i] == arr[j].text {
            idList.push(arr[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```